# Call parent method inside super().__init__ when method is overriden by child

Tags: python, oop

I have overriden a method in a child class.
This method is used in the parent class constructor.
When calling `super().__init__` in the child class the child's method is executed instead of the parent's one inside the parent's constructor.

Example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.method()

    def method(self):
        print('parent method!')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method(self):
        print('child method!')

b = B()
```

Output: `child method!`

While I want to get `parent method!`

Edit:

I need the parent's class constructor to use the not-overriden method, but after that each call to `method()` from the parent class should call overriden one.

Comment: AFAIK, when you have similar method in both parent and child, the child method will get priority for child's instance. Why don't you rename one of them?

Comment: Because I need the parent's contructor to be called with the no-overriden method but then I need to use the overriden one each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I need the parent's contructor to be called with the no-overriden method but then I need to use the overriden one each time.

This indicates you are asking one method to do too many things. Split `method` into two parts: one that is *not* overridden and called by `A.__init__`, and another that *can be* overriden. Something like

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._init_method()

    def _init_method(self):
        print('parent method!')

    def method(self):
        self._init_method()


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method(self):
        print('child method!')

b = B()
```

`_init_method` does what you claim needs to be done from `A.__init__`. At the same time, you can have `method` do the same thing, *unless* you override it, in which case you'll do whatever it is you want `B.method` to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that kind of situation, I would suggest something like:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init()
        self.n_method = 1
    def method(self):
        if self.n_method == 1:
            super().method()
        else:
            do method B stuffs
        self.n_method += 1
```

Comment: This solves it but it is a bit hacky and not very OO. I will upvote it but please check chepner's answer.

Comment: that's a good solution, but I was not sure you want to invoke parent method every time you create a parent's instance.

Answer (score 0):

In `A`'s `__init__()` method, you could write `A.method(self)` rather than `self.method()` to be more explicit about which `method` to call.